# Sharepoint MOSS 2007 advanced search customization

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

In my sharepoint site, the master page template is chagned and we moved the search box into the site which showed as a web part, When the user enters a search string in that box, it should search whatever the materials available in the site itself, document library, blogs in the web, forums and wikis. Therefore, I think I need a way to figure out how these types of searches are done using sharepoint as well as how programmatically provide a search string to advanced search and receive search results. Any Idea how to do this? my code behinds are in C#

Comment: What do you mean by *we moved the search box into the site which showed as a web part*? Did you create a custom search box Web Part?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that should be any issue as sharepoint search is based upon the query string K parameter stands for Keyword, s parameter stands for scope, cs stands for contextual scope So use these parameters in query string to your results page having the core results webpart.
eg.

http:// <>/ <>/ results.aspx?k="Test Keyowrd"&s="All Sites"